# Angular: GET request for template url mysteriously fails 2nd time

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, sharepoint, get

I've got an Angular app which relies on using some template-urls
The app is running in an iframe (please don't question why)
There's a javascript button on the parent page, which reloads the iframe and the angular app during every click.

1st time the click event occurs stuff works brilliant. The app is loaded, while making successful GET request to all my templates-urls.

> Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80 Request
>   URL:http://MyWebsite.com/_layouts/Project/MyAngularApp/angular-templates/term.html
>   Request Method:GET Status Code:200 OK Request Headersview source
>   Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6 Connection:keep-alive
>   Cookie:opened=%23ICD-10-EN_0_class_0_0_1%2C%23ICD-10-EN_2_class_0_0_0%2C%23ICD-10-EN_2_class_12312_0_0%2C%23ICD-10-EN_2_class_12313_0_0%2C%23ICD-10-EN_2_class_12715_0_0;
>   loaded=%23_0_class_0_0_0; selected=%23ICD-10-EN_2_class_12725_0_0;
>   Host:klassifikationer
>   Referer:http://MyWebsite.com/_layouts/Project/MyAngularApp/angularApp.html

But whenever the click event occurs again, all GET requests for template-urls fail

> Request
>   URL:http://MyWebsite.com/_layouts/Project/MyAngularApp/angular-templates/term.html
>   Request Headers Provisional headers are shown Accept:application/json,
>   text/plain, */*
>   Referer:http://MyWebsite.com/_layouts/Project/MyAngularAppr/angularApp.html

and I get this error

***"Error: $compile:tpload Error Loading Template"***. https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload?p0=angular-templates%2Fterm.html

" *Failed to load template: angular-templates/term.html
Description:
This error occurs when $compile attempts to fetch a template from some URL, and the request fails.
To resolve this error, ensure that the URL of the template is spelled correctly and resolves to correct absolute URL. The Chrome Developer Tools might also be helpful in determining why the request failed.
If you are using $templateCache to pre-load templates, ensure that the cache was populated with the template.* "

I've checked the Chrome debugger's Network tab and verified that both the failed and the successful GET requests seem identical. Same request URL, same referer page, same accept argument.

Could the problem concern the $compile directive?
I'm using "tree" directive lib which I found. It allows nested templates and uses the compile directive to build them. Could that be the issue? Here's a demo of the directive [enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JAIyolmqPqO9KsynSiZp?p=preview)

```
 app.directive("tree", function (RecursionHelper) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: { family: '=' },
    controller: 'MyController',
    templateUrl: function(templateElement, templateAttrs) {
        return templateAttrs.templateUrl;
    },
replace: true,
restrict: 'E',
    compile: function (element) {
        // Use the compile function from the RecursionHelper,
        // And return the linking function(s) which it returns
        return RecursionHelper.compile(element);
    }
};
```

});

and here's some example of HTML where the template-url argument is used

```
<div class="repeater" data-ng-repeat="item in content">
    <tree family="item" template-url="angular-templates/term.html"></tree>
</div>
```

Finally, I should also mention that the Angular app is running inside a dotNET project. (sharepoint to be more specific) but I don't think that should be the issue.

Comment: Why are you running in an iframe? Jokes aside, there really shouldn't be a second GET request for the template once its been succesfully fetched once. It would be interesting to see what's going on in the `RecursionHelper`. I can't see anything in your code that uses a `templateUrl` at all. Where does `term.html` fit into all of this?

Comment: So sorry, I forgot that I'm using a modified version of the directive where the 'template' param has been replaced with 'template-url'. I've updated my post to reflect this now.

Comment: "there really shouldn't be a second GET request" - No, that's actually expected. Every the the mentioned click event occurs, the entire iframe is reloaded, and the Angular app within it as well. So that should cause new GET requests